# MySql Error 1064 in C# with xampp

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, mariadb, mysql-error-1064

I keep getting an `Error 1064` with this Text:

> An unhandled exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll
>   Additional information: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '[Tisch 1]' at line 1

This is my Coding:

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace Tischreservierung1000
{
public partial class Reservierung : Form
{

    private MySqlConnection con;
    private MySqlCommand sql;
    private MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection();

public Reservierung()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    String connect = "Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=tischreservierer;uid=Tischreservierer;";
    con = new MySqlConnection(connect);


    //Prüfe ob Tisch 1 schon reserviert ist
    con.Open();
    sql = con.CreateCommand();
    sql.CommandText = "select * from [Tisch 1];";
    MySqlDataReader reader = sql.ExecuteReader(); 
    while (reader.Read()) 
    {
       if (reader.GetString(3) == "Reserviert") { T1Res = false; } else { }
       if (T1Res == false) { T1R.BackgroundImage = null ; T1R.BackColor = Color.DarkRed; T1S1R.BackColor = Color.DarkRed; if (reader.GetInt32(2) == 2) { T1S2R.BackColor = Color.DarkRed; } } else { }   
    }
}
    //Prüfe ob Tisch 2 schon reserviert ist
    sql = con.CreateCommand();
    sql.CommandText = "select * from `Tisch 2`;";
    reader = sql.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
            if (reader.GetString(3) == "Reserviert") { T2Res = false; } else { }
            if (T2Res == false) { T2R.BackgroundImage = null; T2R.BackColor = Color.DarkRed; T2S1R.BackColor = Color.DarkRed; if (reader.GetInt32(2) == 2) { T2S2R.BackColor = Color.DarkRed; } } else { }
    }
```

}

The error shows up in this line:

```
MySqlDataReader reader = sql.ExecuteReader();
```

Why is he trying to get a Connection to MariaDB?
I used the Access Database before and it worked this way.

It helped with the Backticks. But now im getting following Error:
There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.

Error Code Line @ "Tisch 2":

reader = sql.ExecuteReader();

(Ive added it above)

Thanks for your help

Comment: In mysql the delimiter is the backtick, replace the brackets with backticks `"select * from \`Tisch 1\`;"`

Comment: Thanks, that helped! but im getting the next error right under my code i posted:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delimiter you are using is the SQL delimiter, not the MySQL delimiter.
Use ` instead of [ and ].

Comment: But i knew what he meant ^^ so it helped me too. Thanks to both of you.

Comment: Updated to use the backtick.